# CRM reporting Extension - SSRS instance is blank

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2016, sql-server-2017

Trying to install Reporting Extension for CRM 2016 but SSRS instance is blank.

VM containing (SQL & CRM on the **same machine**)

- Windows Server 2016
- SQL Server 2017 - Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU6) (KB4101464) - 14.0.3025.34 (X64)   Apr  9 2018 18:00:41   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
- Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server already installed on VM
- Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services is running and I am able to browse the reporting URL
- SQL, CRM and reporting are installed using same account 'administrator'. This is part of "PrivReportingGroup" as mentioned in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699754.aspx#sql_server_reporting_services
- SQL server has default instance only

Can you please help me how to fix the error below (SSRS instance name is empty). Can we install reporting extension on **SQL server 2017** (should be OK as I was able to install CRM server)?

[image]

Comment: Try running the Report Extension installer on DB server (Where SSRS installed) instead of AP Server. [Ref1](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2012/12/27/ssrs-extension-installation-does-not-display-ssrs-instances-crm-2011/) [Ref2](http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.com/2014/03/crm-20112013-cannot-find-ssrs-instance.html)

Answer (score 3):

1) Download nssm util - https://nssm.cc/download

2) Unzip nssm.exe and copy to windir (c:\windows)

3) Run cmd as administrator and then command : **nssm install ReportServer$SSRS c:\windows\notepad.exe**

4) Start service ReportServer$SSRS  ( **net start ReportServer$SSRS** )

5) Open registry **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SSRS\Setup** and add REG_SZ attribute with name **Version** and value '14.0.600.1572'   (SSRS version)

6) Install crm connector (**SetupSrsDataConnector.exe**)

7) Install latest patch for crm convertor (greather then 0.3) - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3142345/microsoft-dynamics-365-onpremise-cumulative-updates (CRM9.0-Srs-KBXXXXXX-ENU-Amd64.exe)

8) Restart server

9) Stop service ReportServer$SSRS  ( **net stop ReportServer$SSRS** )

10) Remove dummy service : **nssm remove ReportServer$SSRS confirm**

11) Optional - delete nssm.exe from windows directory

Comment: If you are prohibited from running external tools or executables, you could use the built in SC.EXE command line program in Windows Server for steps 3 and 10 above like this:
3. SC.EXE create ReportServer$SSRS binpath = "c:\Windows\Notepad.exe"
10.  SC.EXE delete ReportServer$SSRS

Comment: Interestingly I installed the latest V9 cumulative update (CRM9.0-Srs-KB5014429-ENU-Amd64.exe) and it still did not work. However after uninstalling the update and restarting the server, the dynamics-reports started working.

Answer (score 2):

Search for CRM reporting Extension - SSRS instance is blank.

1. Make sure that in the Report Server Configuration Manager there is specified a service account which is a member of PrivReportingGroup and has a *write permissions* to this group. This account must not be a member of SQLAccessGroup. At least during installation.
2. The setup program also needs a windows service names exactly 'ReportServer$SSRS'. To achieve this, just create a dummy blank new service with a specified name and register it using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
3. After that, we need to open Regedit.exe to make changes that will allow the setup program to discover and validate our SSRS instance.

   1. In [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS] branch add new REG_SZ attribute with name 'MSSQLSERVER' and value 'SSRS'
   2. In [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SSRS\Setup] branch add new REG_SZ attribute with name 'Version' and value '14.0.600.906' (in my case, you should use your version of SQL server)
4. Now run the setup program (SetupSrsDataConnector.exe). Some next step must show our SSRS instance and we choose it. After all the steps done we will get the last step with important System Checks which all must be green, thanks to our preparation actions.

Voilà! Setup completed successfully.

5. Manually restart SSRS using stop and start buttons in Report Server Configuration Manager.
6. Finally, check in the /Reports web application. Open any data source and check that a new data source type options have appeared

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps... Added the SSRS via the NSSM / Kibana steps I discovered. Started the SSRS services and they are running, created the two Registry keys as shown above, reran my SetupSrsDataConnector.exe via the .exe itself and not via the GUI for Dynamics, I now SEE the SSRS "entry" and select next BUT then I error out on the check... "Unable to validate SQL Server Reporting Services Report Server installation. Please check that it is correctly installed on the local machine."

I ASSUME the instance is is due to creating a fake SSRS instance to be selected... I have been stuck on this for nearly TWO days. Please advise,